# recursive search an array on the basis of key in php

Tags: php, regex, arrays, cakephp

I need a php function that will recursively search an array on the basis of key I provided. and want to get an array as return output containing all the values those are mapped with the searched key.

For e.g.:

```
[Case] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [CASE_ID] => 2233
                [CHECK_ID] => 57
                [CLIENT_ID] => 78
            )
        [2] => Array
            (
                [CASE_ID] => 9542
                [CHECK_ID] => 45
                [CLIENT_ID] => 18
            )
     )
```

If I would pass this array and key `CHECK_ID`, then it should return me an array containing `57,45`. Kindly ask if you need more explanation. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: No matter you use recursive function or not. I need an array that will find array key irrespective of whatever be the depth level of that array using `array_map()` or any other php core methods.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Walking the array and chucking found keys into a new one:

```
function find_matches($array, $value) {
    $found = array();
    array_walk_recursive($array,
        function ($item, $key) use ($value, &$found) {
            if ($value === $key) {
                $found[] = $item;
            }
        }
    );
    return $found;
}
```

see http://codepad.viper-7.com/dVmYOT

Have you also considered using [find('list')](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/retrieving-your-data.html#find-list) with a `fields` condition restriction?

Comment: But it will only find $value at the top level http://se.php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk-recursive.php, "Any key that holds an array will not be passed to the function."

Comment: @Vic, if by 'top level' you mean [CASE_ID] and 'bottom level' you mean [Case], then yes, this will only match keys to non-array values.

I'd guess though that this is all that OP needs.

Answer (score 2):

Just check each element, filter based on key, convert the outcome to an array:

```
$filter = function($c, $key) {
    return $key === 'CHECK_ID';
};
$filtered = new CallbackFilterIterator(
    new RecursiveIteratorIterator(
        new RecursiveArrayIterator($array)
    ),
    $filter
);
var_dump(iterator_to_array($filtered, false));
```

Result:

```
array(2) {
  [0] =>
  int(57)
  [1] =>
  int(45)
}
```

Comment: +1, great answer, but it should be mentioned that `CallbackFilterIterator` works only with php5.4 or higher.

Comment: @mamdouhalramadan: Which is the previous stable version of PHP 5.4. It actually works in all stable versions of PHP. Also it's easy to create one in PHP 5.3 or lower. I'll add such one to Iterator Garden as well, will post the link to the development trunk after a short break.

Comment: Here you go, np: https://github.com/hakre/Iterator-Garden/blob/development/src/CallbackFilterIterator.php - as written this is pretty straight forward. Ping me if you run into a problem with it.

Answer (score 1):

```
function array_rfind($find, $arr) {
  $found = array();
  foreach($arr as $key => $val) {
    if($key == $find)
      $found[] = $val;
    elseif(is_array($val))
      $found = array_merge($found, array_rfind($find, $val));
  }
  return $found;
}
```

Comment: Giving a weird result containing extra merged array that did not contain that key.

Comment: The result is not weird :) it gives you all values in the array having $find as key. The resulting array will be one dimensional. Is there something I have missundertood in you question?

Comment: Try with an array not containing the `searched Key` at the same level. means try to enter it into `elseif` condition. The array will be merged with that. Anyways 1+ for your valuable effort.